# Open Google Docs Spreadsheet via URL (and also login directly)

Tags: python, url, gdata

I have a python script which opens up a spreadsheet in a browser given a key (attained via gdata api..link would be like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ace6G_SArx1ldEU4UHZBUDNNQzVnRGxMblFfcEp1LXc). However, I want to automatically login using this URL as well (given a username and password). At the end of it, I would automatically login and open up a certain spreadsheet.

Any help?